# VisualStudio-based Rich Client Platform

Tags: visual-studio, rich-client-platform

I remember hearing about a rich client platform based on Visual Studio, similar to Eclipse's Rich Client Platform, that gives you things like auto updates, shells, help system and so on built in. I can't seem to find it on Google though, does anyone remember what this was called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx)?

Comment: That was probably it, thanks. I had thought it was more general purpose though, not just limited to programming shells.

Comment: Maybe WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) ? This is the system that renders the graphical part of Visual Studio. It doesn't do updates or implement a help system.